# Compile constraints for NMinimize

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, compile

I use complicated constraints for optimisation, something like

```
Table[
   EuclideanDistance[pts[[i]], pts[[j]]] >= 1
     , {i, numPts - 1}, {j, i + 1, numPts}]
```

Is it possible (and will it be useful) to compile these constraints
before using with `NMinimize`?

Comment: Maybe. You have to try yourself. But I doubt, that `NMinimize` would work well at all. This is a global minimization routine and it is typically now very efficient for nonconvex problems. For large `numPts`, one would also prefer to use `Nearest` to reduce the complexity from $O(\mathrm{numPts}^2)$ to $O(\mathrm{numPts} \, \log(\mathrm{numPts}))$.